# I need to change the column name in the VO.xml . But changes are not reflected in the application

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oaf

i have changed the xxxxVO.xml flie for a VO object .
Changes are very minor as i wanted to inter change one of the column name which was already there in the table.
As i had alias to that column name  , output would be the same .
I have made changes in VO.xml file from notepad plus and replaced in the server.

I have performed apache, oacore bounce and jar recreate .
But my changes are not reflected from the application .
When i go to aboutthispage i see the old VO query .

Please suggest if i have missed any step in making this change .

Answer (score 0):

Did you try opening the VO xml on server and see what it holds?

Also is the VO SQL based or EO based. If it is EO based, you may also need to double check your attribute mappings in VO.xml.